# how to update blankContent in simpledialog2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using simpledialog2 plugin and and it works fine but i want to refresh the contents without closing it. i.e i have a button which should modify the content of the dialog. Can anybody suggest how to clear and update blank content of simpledialog2 without calling it twice. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want like this 
[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/visnupriya/7YpkR/2/)

Code is here:

```
$(document).delegate('#opendialog', 'click', function() {
  // NOTE: The selector can be whatever you like, so long as it is an HTML element.
  //       If you prefer, it can be a member of the current page, or an anonymous div
  //       like shown.
  $('<div>').simpledialog2({
mode: 'blank',
        headerText: 'Alert',
        headerClose: true,
        blankContent : 
          "<br/><br/><br/><p id='test_content'>Test Test Test Test</p>"+
        "<a href='#' data-role='button' id='accept_time_btn'>Accept</a>"
   })

})                   
$('#accept_time_btn').live("click",function(){
  // alert(work_order_id)
 $('#test_content').html("Update Test Contents");

});
```

Comment: Thanks vishnu it was of great help :)

Answer (score 0):

The above example works sometime but there is a property which has to be set true i.e dialogAllow. See below code

```
            $('div').simpledialog2({
                mode : 'blank',
                headerText : "Some text",
                headerClose: true,
                dialogAllow: true,
                dialogForce: false,
                showModal:true,
                blankContent :rhtml

              });
```

Above code is to show Dialog with blank HTML or may contain some HTML content

Below two statement will help to update content on existing simpledialog without calling it again
$.mobile.sdCurrentDialog.updateBlank(rhtml);
$('div').simpledialog2('refresh');

Hope this helps you 
Summved